# R.regression.multi land-use data not enough valid cells

Tags: grass-gis, regression, land-use, qgis-grass-plugin, rgrass7

**What I want:** run r.regression.multi between land-use change and bumblebee occurrence.

**What I did:**

- X coefficients: cov_all.0 of North, East, South and West SSP1 -4 layers in total. (I projected the data in ESPG:3035 by exporting and saving as geoTIFF + changing projection: https://surfdrive.surf.nl/files/index.php/s/3O4FKJBLU9hvw4z?path=%2FSSP-1-CLUMondo%2FEast)
- Y-coefficient: bumblebee occurrence (Saved point data as GEOpackage, used vector to raster to rasterize, is now a float 32 raster file in multiband pseudocolour. Supplementary material 5: https://oneecosystem.pensoft.net/article/28143/element/5/4349567//)
- Have clipped all layers to include the European Union + UK and Greece

**Errors:**
ERROR: Not enough valid cells available
ERROR: Raster map  not found
ERROR: Raster map or group  not found
ERROR: Raster map  not found
ERROR: Raster map or group  not found

**Question:** there is a lot of data in the files and a lot of valid cells, how can I run the r.regression.multi successfully?

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the data layers from the links you supplied. First, the cov_all are single band rasters with values from 1-21 (I assume land cover classes). And they are already projected in EPSG:3035. No problem to import directly.

Next, the bumble bee dataset X-Y are, it seems, also already in EPSG:3035. And the points are on a regular grid of 10,000m. This point data can be imported into GRASS directly as a raster using the `r.in.xyz` modules. The data has about 50 columns, the last of which is "CompositeProbability". I assumed that you want that value as your Y variable.

After importing as above, you can then run the regression module. Here, below is the code I ran, and the table of regression results. So the code works on your data, but I have no idea if the results make sense :-)

```
# Start GRASS, creating a new LOCATION, based on EPSG:3035
# I ran this in the directory that holds the downloaded rasters, for convenience
grass -c EPSG:3035 ./grassdata

# Now inside a GRASS session
# Check the CRS 
g.proj -p

# Setup external links to all ASC files
# These ASC rasters are already in EPSG:3035
# but there is no CRS defined in ASC format, so use the '-c' flag to avoid checking CRS
r.external -o cov_all.0.asc output=cov_east
r.external -o "cov_all.0(1).asc" output=cov_north
r.external -o "cov_all.0(2).asc" output=cov_south
r.external -o "cov_all.0(3).asc" output=cov_west

# Set Computational Region to cover all cover rasters
g.region -ap rast=cov_east,cov_north,cov_south,cov_west

# Patch together the four rasters
r.patch input=cov_north,cov_east,cov_south,cov_west output=cov

# The bumble bee points are on a regular grid of 10,000 m
# Reset the computation region to match that grid
g.region -ap res=10000

# The r.in.xyz module is suitable for creating raster from gridded points
# Import using the CompositeProbability column as raster values
r.in.xyz input=oo_202234.csv output=bb_prob x=1 y=2 value_col=51 skip=1 sep=comma

# Run regression
r.regression.multi mapx=cov mapy=bb_prob resid=bb_resids estim=bb_estim output=bb_regression.txt

# Results
cat regression.txt
n=43356
Rsq=0.000782
Rsqadj=0.000759
RMSE=0.128330
MAE=0.107745
F=33.924946
b0=0.323681
AIC=-178028.758774
AICc=-178028.758774
BIC=-178011.404373

predictor1=cov
```

Since the cov_all rasters are, I think, landcover classification, the values of each class have no meaning. That's most likely the reason that the above regression results are so poor. Did you want to separate the landcover classes and use each as a separate X predictor variable?

HTH

Comment: "Did you want to separate the landcover classes and use each as a separate X predictor variable?" actually that would be much better, but is that possible given that they are marched into one raster layer?

Comment: Yes, of course. You would use, i.e. `r.mapcalc` to extract each landcover of interest inot a separate raster. These would have values of 1 for pixels within the chosen landcover, and NA for all other pixels. Then use that collection of rasters in the `r.regression.multi`.

Comment: And, taking this a step further, note that **all** your explanatory variables are actually discrete classes, and not continuous values, maybe a regression analysis is not the right approach from the start...  If part of the variables were continuous and part were classes, OK. But in this case perhaps some ANOVA or similar might be more appropriate.